# error due to single quotes in insert query

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am inserting values in a Mysql database from java file using -

```
String query = "INSERT INTO genes (sent, title) VALUES ('"+sent+"','"+title+"')";
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
int rs = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

where `sent` and `title` are variable strings extracted after applying some algorithm. But this gives sql error when `sent` or `title` contains single qoutes.

Comment: Consider using iBatis / myBatis:

http://blog.mybatis.org/

Or JPA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using a prepared statement with parameters:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO genes (sent, title) VALUES (?, ?)");
pstmt.setString(1, sent);
pstmt.setString(2, title);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) in fill the query parameters. It takes care of escaping the single quotes if any in the input parameters.

Modify your query and statement object as follows and it should be working:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO genes (sent, title) VALUES (? , ?)";
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement( query );
pst.setString( 1, sent );
pst.setString( 2, title );

int insertResult = pst.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `PreparedStatements` for that. **[PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)** is under `java.sql.*` namespace.

```
String insertString = "INSERT INTO genes (sent, title) VALUES (?,?)";
// con is your active connection
PreparedStatement insertX = con.prepareStatement(updateString); 
insertX.setString(1, sent);
insertX.setString(2, title);
insertX.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never concatenate SQL statements like this, instead, use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html):

```
String query = "INSERT INTO genes (sent, title) VALUES (?,?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

p.setString(1, sent);
p.setString(2, title);
p.executeUpdate();
```

If you use the string concatenation method you are exposing yourself to dangerous [sql-injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: +1 Because the only answer mentioning sql-injection. It is scary to see that no one else mentioned this.

Answer (score 1):

```
String query = "INSERT INTO genes (sent, title) VALUES (?, ?)";
PreparedStatement pt = con.prepareStatement(query);
pt.setString(1, sent);
pt.setString(2, title);
pt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, Remove `'` from string or replace by `\'` from `'`.

Mysql allow only in `\'` format for special character.